# G Suite calendar and mail integration

Tags: email, calendar, google-workspace

We use the Google Suite for corporate email, calendar etc. What I am trying to achieve here is, I need to be compose an email in gmail with a link to a calendar invite. I would also be able to fill in the details of the meeting through the invite which is embedded in the email. For example, I should be able to send an invite to xyz at company.com with subject Meeting to discuss status and with the body of Test Message. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is just use standard invitation. You just simply add new calendar event and set guests:

1. Open Google Calendar
2. Open an event, or create a new one. Specify event title and description - it will be then stated in the invitation email...
3. On the right, find the "Guests" section.
4. Start typing the name of the person and choose someone from your contacts. You can also type an email address to invite people who aren't in your contacts list.
5. When you're done editing your event, click Save.

When you save your event, an email invitation will be sent to your guests.
What is also good, there is .ics file in attachment of invitation email - can be useful for non google recipients using another email clients.

However, if you need URL of the event, you can get it on the event edit page in google calendar - there is a link on the bottom of the page: "publish event" - you can copy the link of the event there. But please be aware that the Google calendar the event is tied to needs to be public (or shared with the recipients), and not just the event itself. (This link is useful for google calendar users...)